Time Machine fails to back up to NAS with error "The backup disk image could not be created."
On Monterey 12.7.4, I have used Time Machine to back up to an external hard drive. However, I would like to set up an additional network backup location so I don't have to remember to plug in my external drive. I have set up the samba share that I intend to use and am able to mount the share successfully on my mac. I see that I have read and write privileges and am able to create files and folders (ls -l shows drwx------). I am also able to view the share in Time Machine, and have set up Time Machine to use the share as an additional backup location. When I run Time Machine, it begins to run and see that a sparsebundle is created on share.
However, seconds later, the backup fails and an exclamation mark appears next to the share location stating "Time Machine couldn’t complete the backup to "my share" The backup disk image could not be created." How can I fix this error and get backups working properly? I am especially perplexed because the sparsebundle does briefly appear in Finder and then quickly disappears at the time the backup fails.
Edit:
Including my smb.conf here:
[backups]

   comment=*name*

   path=*/path/to/share*

   read only=no

   valid users=*username*

   vfs objects=catia fruit streams_xattr

   fruit:time machine=yes


What kind of device are you using as an SMB server? If applicable, post the contents of smb.conf on the server. Also, is any third-party "anti-virus" software installed on the Mac?

smb is running on a raspberry pi 4b. I've added the relevant smb.conf entry above. Turns out there was an old install of Malwarebytes on my machine, but it wasn't doing anything as far as I'm aware. I've removed it and am seeing the same behavior.

Well, I am no expert on that platform, but I see some reports that adding the following directive to smb.conf solved the problem you seem to have: fruit:metadata = stream See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61070777/issue-using-samba-4-9-with-time-machine

I did this a long time ago on a Windows server platform (please forgive the lack of detail)  and found that if you create a sparse disk image, move it to your share and then open/mount it on the Mac. you can then point Time Machine to the mounted volume as the backup destination and macOS will remember the rest.

@LincD. I tried adding and restarting the samba service but it doesn't fix the issue.

@SteveChambers This is interesting. I created an image directly on the share using hdiutil create -type SPARSE -fs APFS -volname *volname* *filename* but when I tried to mount it, got the error:  "The disk image couldn't be opened. There are no mountable file systems in the disk image." Similarly, when I created one locally and tried to copy to the share, I got "unable to move extended attributes and ACL from filename: Attribute not found." So, I created an HFS+ volume instead, which mounts successfully but does not appear as possible backup location in Time Machine.

I wanted to add a note that the external drive I'm trying to use for the backup with Samba is formatted ExFat. I'm increasingly suspicious that this is causing the many issues I'm seeing.

It doesn't look like this is a macOS issue. The best I can do is point you to a detailed tutorial for the setup you want. Note that the backup volume is formatted as Btrfs, not ExFAT: https://ovechkin.xyz/blog/2022-01-16-321-backup-setting-rpi-for-time-machine

If I recall correctly it took me a couple of tries to get the sparse image correct, which I did in Disk Utility. You want to create it on the Mac, mount it and then format it with the filesystem type you prefer. At the time APFS was not available as a target for Time Machine. Once you have formatted the mounted image you can un mount it and move it to the SMB share. Of further note I just used the GUI in Disk utility to do everything. It shouldn't make a difference but the computer support tech in me thinks that maybe it makes a difference, even though it should not.

I will try to use this process and report back: https://mybyways.com/blog/using-an-exfat-drive-for-time-machine-backups

I've attempted the solution above as well as several others (i.e., https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254183418?sortBy=best) and have been unable to find something that works. I was eventually able to correctly generate, name, and copy over a sparsebundle to my network location, only to have Time Machine delete the sparsebundle file and fail the backup

I have a similar issue. I have a bit more information. I can see it creating the sparse bundle on the server, and using du -h  can see the sparse bundle growing in size. It grows to about 1.6G in size over about 30 seconds, then drops back to 771M in size, then the process fails with the error message "Unable to create disk image".
It did create it, and added things to that bundle. I do note that other internet searches suggest that the name of the sparse bundle should be a combination of machine name and MAC address. Mine is 2C25DB10-6C01-598B-9C11-383D64CA7A37_2024-08-31-155932

Interesting @PaulL, this is similar to what I see, but the sparse bundle does not grow in size and the backup fails very quickly (in a second or two).

I think I found the answer to this.
Mine appeared to be creating a sparse file named with a file system UID (something like 2C25DB10-6C01-598B-9C11-383D64CA7A37_2024-08-31-175707.sparsebundle). It then errored out.
I found an option for the smb.conf that I previously didn't have set:
fruit:posix_rename = yes
When I set this value, it then works.
My hypothesis is that it creates the sparsebundle, then renames it to "Pauls Macbook.sparsebundle". Without the rename option set, it cannot rename the sparsebundle and fails.
This option is documented on the official Samba page https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Configure_Samba_to_Work_Better_with_Mac_OS_X , but not in many of the older posts of working smb.conf files.

I've tried setting this as a global option and for the individual share, restarting the service with systemctl restart smb.service, and running a backup, but backup still fails in the same way. I think this might address some issues but there seems to be something else causing trouble on my setup.

Used your advice and renamed manually to proper one (from uuid to human readable one from Finder sidebar) and it started to backup.
Rename it manually because my setup is Keenetic Router + 4TB HDD. Can't find manual configuration for such options.
